# How to fix error while using "INSERT INTO'?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to drop an entire table into another table. The number of columns, their names and types are completely identical.
Somehow I am not able to get this done because of an error.

Case_Data Table:

[image: Case_Data Table]

POC_CD Table:

[image: POC_CD Table]

Code :

```
insert into [dbo].[POC_CD] select * from [dbo].[Case_Data]
```

Error :

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
>   date and/or time from character string.

**Edit : Create Table Code for the two tables**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[POC_CD](
    [Case Type] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Category] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Client] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [L2/L3 User] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Number] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Opened] [datetime] NULL,
    [Organization] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Priority] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Product] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Resolved] [datetime] NULL,
    [Resolution Code] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Scheduled Follow Up] [datetime] NULL,
    [State] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Subcategory] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [TicketSummary] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Updated] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Case_Data](
    [Number] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [State] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Priority] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Organization] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Client] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Product] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Category] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Subcategory] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Ticket Summary] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Case Type] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Resolved] [datetime] NULL,
    [Opened] [datetime] NULL,
    [Scheduled Follow Up] [datetime] NULL,
    [Resolution code] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [L2/L3 User] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Updated] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: Is the column *order* also identical? Do yourself a favor and write out the full column list in the `SELECT` and `INSERT` (from SSMS, this is easily automated by right-clicking it and selecting "Script Table as -> Select to -> New query editor window").

Comment: The error message tells the structure is not identical, at the very least by the ordering. Name each column at the `INSERT` and in the `SELECT` portions.

Comment: structure is not identical

Comment: A casual glance at the images you've linked shows that the tables are ***not*** "completely identical".

Comment: Instead of using `*`, and omitting them in the `INSERT` define your columns. It *could* be as simple as the columns are in a different order. Ordinal posutoon defines what column is inserted into what, not name/alias.

Comment: Select the query in SSMS and hith `Ctrl+Shift+Q`. This will bring up the query designer that expands `*` into the actual columns. You can use this to quickly get all the column names in the query text. After that, add the correct column names in the `INSERT INTO` clause and make sure they match the columns in the `SELECT` clause

Comment: From Ahmed Boukil : *You must check column types between source table and destination table . if there is difference you could convert this column to the right type*

Comment: Thanks, guys. I was able to fix it by replacing the * with column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LtB7.png)

You must edit the order of the columns like this :

```
Insert into [dbo].[POC_CD](  [Number] ,[State] ,[Priority],[Organization] ,[Client] ,[Product] ,[Category] ,[Subcategory],[Ticket Summary] ,[Case Type] ,[Resolved] ,[Opened] ,[Scheduled Follow Up] ,[Resolution code] ,[L2/L3 User] ,[Updated])
select   [Number]
 [Number] ,[State] ,[Priority],[Organization] ,[Client] ,[Product] ,[Category] ,[Subcategory],[Ticket Summary] ,[Case Type] ,[Resolved] ,[Opened] ,[Scheduled Follow Up] ,[Resolution code] ,[L2/L3 User] ,[Updated] from [dbo].[Case_Data]
```

with the same order between insert and select columns

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.